# How do I navigate to specific screen by pressing android hardware back button in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native. And I want to Navigate Or go to specific page when I press android hardware back button. is it possible . if yes
please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like below;

```
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native'
```

Then inside your react component;

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("your_screen");
    return true;
}
```

In react hooks / functional components;

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

function handleBackButtonClick() {
    ... // do something
    return true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: any other method alternative of this method

Comment: or just tell me in which case my code getting problem. sometimes its not working .

Comment: you already posted a question on that and we had a discussion. As i told you there that i tried it with both stack as well as drawer navigator and it is working fine and i requested to upload more code.

Comment: As per this question is concerned, my answer satisfies this completely. I used it number of times and it works fine. So you should mark this as accepted and turn your attention towards your older question as that is the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

For functional components:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBack);
    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);
```

Comment: You should check my answer. I already added that.

Comment: It was an edit. Wasn't there when I was writing my answer... Edited 2 min after my answer :)